# How to prepare data for time series RNN

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, rnn

Our goal is to predict different mixtures of gases in case of an air pollution or in space shuttles.We have measurements that are taken from medical devices and we are taking measurements from multiple people (or mice).

For each test there are start parameters (such as the amount of oxygen in the room) and dosages of medical drugs that we give to the mice at different dosages. At the end of each test we know if the dosages were correct. The samples are taken every second.

The sample data below shows a number of lines from one file from one test. "-" is a missing value.

The third column is the ID of the subject.
The first and second columns are mostly 0 but sometime there are values there.

````
0 0 7025  STATE-2 0.790039V 128V 6V - 126.6SI 378.6SI 0:00:00 0:00:03 0V 0V 0V 48V 0V 0V - - - 14f8 - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.915 0.457 40 1448 10 - 2387 4532 62264

0 0 7007  STATE-2 0.775391V 128V 1V - 99.9SI 298.9SI 0:00:00 0:00:01 0V 0V 0V 20V 0V 0V - - - 1518 - - - - "7,7" 202 - 1.159 0.579 40 1448 10 - 568 910 66608

0 0 7027  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 36s 0 10ea - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7076  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 40s 0 119f - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7033  STATE-2 1V 128V 4V - 134.9SI 403.3SI 0:00:00 0:00:02 0V 0V 0V 64V 0V 0V - - - 14f9 - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.859 0.429 40 1448 10 - 1712 3111 81088

0 0 7047  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 41s 0 12Vd - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7003  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 39s 0 11a5 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7008  STATE-2 1V 128V 8V - 121.3SI 362.7SI - 0:00:03 0V 0V 0V 84V 0V 0V - - - 1.40E+02 - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.955 0.477 40 1448 10 - 2857 6006 114392

0 0 7007  STATE-2 1V 128V 3V - 144.8SI 433.0SI 0:00:00 0:00:01 0V 0V 0V 48V 0V 0V - - - 1519 - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.8 0.4 40 1448 10 - 1103 1940 83984

0 0 7074  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 40s 0 12c5 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

2896 0 7008  STATE-2 1V 128V 8V - 102.0SI 304.9SI - 0:00:03 4V 0V 0V 80V 0V 0V - - - 1.40E+03 - - - - "7,7" 202 - 1.136 0.568 40 1448 10 - 2859 6008 111496

0 0 7033  STATE-2 1V 128V 4V - 142.7SI 426.6SI 0:00:00 0:00:02 0V 0V 0V 64V 0V 0V - - - 14fa - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.812 0.406 40 1448 10 - 1699 3109 81088

0 0 7043  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 35s 0 10d4 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7090  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 39s 0 11V0 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7010  STATE-2 1V 128V 6V - 136.6SI 408.5SI 0:00:00 0:00:03 0V 0V 0V 56V 0V 0V - - - 14fV - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.848 0.424 40 1448 10 - 2485 4666 69504

0 0 7007  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 28s 0 1029 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7035  STATE-2 0.727539V 128V 3V - 145.5SI 435.2SI 0:00:00 0:00:02 16V 0V 0V 20V 0V 0V - - - 151a - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.796 0.398 40 1448 10 - 1203 2183 55024

0 0 7066  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 42s 0 11V2 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7035  STATE-2 0.727539V 128V 3V - 142.8SI 427.1SI 0:00:00 0:00:02 0V 0V 0V 36V 0V 0V - - - 151V - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.811 0.405 40 1448 10 - 1205 2185 55024

0 0 7033  STATE-2 0.730469V 128V 2V - 14.8SI 44.3SI 0:00:00 0:00:02 0V 0V 0V 36V 0V 0V - - - 14fc - - - - "7,7" 208 - 7.828 3.914 40 1448 10 - 844 1430 70952

0 0 7064  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 40s 0 11V9 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7025  STATE-2 0.608398V 128V 6V - 145.2SI 434.1SI 0:00:00 0:00:03 0V 0V 0V 52V 0V 0V - - - 14fd - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.798 0.399 40 1448 10 - 2368 4543 62264

0 0 7025  STATE-2 0.849609V 128V 6V - 137.3SI 410.4SI 0:00:00 0:00:03 0V 0V 0V 44V 0V 0V - - - 14fe - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.844 0.422 40 1448 10 - 2382 4542 60816

0 0 7058  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 39s 0 1159 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7083  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 40s 0 115V - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7022  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 29s 0 1050 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7009  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 43s 0 11c3 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7001  STATE-2 3V 128V 12V - 285.3SI 853.2SI 0:00:00 0:00:03 0V 0V 0V 192V 0V 0V - - - 1.40E+04 - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.406 0.203 40 1448 10 - 3806 8346 254848

0 0 7016  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 42s 0 1.20E+04 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7095  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 43s 0 11c4 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7098  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 40s 0 11c5 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7008  STATE-2 1V 128V 8V - 143.2SI 428.2SI 0:00:00 0:00:03 0V 0V 0V 88V 0V 0V - - - 1.40E+05 - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.809 0.404 40 1448 10 - 2860 6022 111496

2896 0 7001  STATE-2 3V 128V 12V - 293.3SI 877.0SI - 0:00:03 4V 2V 0V 176V 0V 0V - - - 1.40E+06 - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.395 0.197 40 1448 10 - 3761 8339 234576

0 0 7069  STATE-1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - STATE-1 35s 0 10d7 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

0 0 7033  STATE-2 0.81543V 128V 4V - 140.9SI 421.4SI 0:00:00 0:00:02 0V 0V 0V 72V 0V 0V - - - 14ff - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.822 0.411 40 1448 10 - 1671 3109 88328

0 0 7035  STATE-2 0.357422V 128V 124V 4V 31.6SI 353.1SI 0:00:02 0:00:02 0V 0V 0V 
0V 0V 0V - - - 151c - - - - "7,7" 206 - 5.13 8.47 40 1448 14 - 7 9 28960

0 0 7007  STATE-2 0.599609V 128V 3V - 144.4SI 431.9SI - 0:00:01 0V 0V 0V 52V 0V 0V - - - 151d - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.802 0.401 40 1448 10 - 1068 1942 65160

0 0 7022  STATE-2 0.532227V 128V 2V - 140.9SI 421.4SI 0:00:00 0:00:01 0V 0V 0V 28V 0V 0V - - - 151e - - - - "7,7" 201 - 0.822 0.411 40 1448 10 - 954 1743 47784

0 0 7007  STATE-2 0.357422V 128V 124V 4V 28.5SI 420.9SI 0:00:01 0:00:01 0V 0V 0V 0V 0V 0V - - - 151f - - - - "7,7" 206 - 5.289 9.106 40 1448 13 - 6 8 28960
```
````